# Add packages to pylint exceptions

Tags: python, numpy, spyder, pylint, static-code-analysis

I'm using pylint with spyder but when I evaluate the static code analysis it claims that numpy doesn't have any members.
Does anyone know a way to add python packages to some sort of universal exceptions list so that pyline will just skip them?
I've hit a bit of a brick wall with Google - some sources refer to a "*.rc" file, but I can't find it anywhere...

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it will work, but try this.  Create a ~/.pylintrc file, and put this in it:

```
[MASTER]

extension-pkg-whitelist=numpy
```

Comment: Hi mepstein thanks for getting back to me.  I've made what I think is the right file, added your suggested line, and saved it as "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pylint\standard.rc".  I've then added the line 'python "%~dpn0" %* --rcfile="C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\pylint\standard.rc"' to the end of each pylint batch file on the path "C:\Python34\Scripts" but it still doesn't seem to work....